# Unity Change Canvas Size as Portrait (mobile size)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

How to change the canvas default scale (landscape) to portrait / match with mobile view? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the line below whenever you need.

```
    Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
```

Changing display orientation doesn't depend on Canvas but Canvas changes upon display orientation. So when orientation changes, canvas orientation does same.

Be aware of using UI components in a way so that it doesn't look bad when display orientation changes.